# Aggregating across columns of data table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data.table that looks like

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 ....
E01 ASD DSA 9  2  1  22 4
E03 SDF FDX 21 9  0  10 2
E04 MAX XXX 77 2  .5 23 1.5 ..
```

For each ID1 (and leaving ID2 and ID3 unaltered), I would like to compute the mean of different subgroups of Xx, the output should look like

```
ID1 ID2 ID3 av_X1_X3 av_X4_X5   ...
E01 ASD DSA 4        13         ...
E03 SDF FDX 10       6
```

Xx ranges from X0 to X90 and I need to be able to easily input three to five possible groupings of Xx.

Comment: Why is `av_X1_X3` 4 in the first row? Not 5?

Comment: 9+2+1=12
12/3=4 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention how subgroups is defined. If you intended to do it manually for each subgroup, this should not be too hard to input

```
s <- "ID1 ID2 ID3 X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
E01 ASD DSA 9  2  1  22 4
E03 SDF FDX 21 9  0  10 2
E04 MAX XXX 77 2  .5 23 1.5"

dt <- fread(s)
dt[, av_X1_X3 := mean(c(X1, X3)), by = ID1]
```

To add more columns in one line:

```
dt[, `:=`(av_X1_X3 = mean(c(X1,X3)), av_X4_X5 = mean(c(X4,X5))),by=ID1]
```

Comment: Thanks! It will be manual, can I insert a list of such definitions in j ?

E.g.: dt[,.(av_X1_X3 :=mean(c(X1,X3)), av_X4_X5 :=mean(c(X4,X5))),by=ID1)

Comment: Sure, but the syntax will be a little bit different. see edit in answer.

Comment: @ThreeDiag Sorry I'm not quite sure about the edit you purposed `av_X1_X3 = mean(c(X1,X2,X3))` If you want av_X1_X2_X3, that's all right, but the variable name really should match its meaning. And in concept there is not much difference of use X1_X2 or X1_X2_X3 in this answer, since you are asking the general method instead of specific result.

Comment: That was what I inteded to do, as implied by the example, in that I was looking for a way to get the average of the cols from X1 to X3. It's a minor thing anyway. Additionaly, the sintax dt[, av_X1_X3 := mean(X1:X3), by=ID1] also does what I wanted (for longer sequences of cols).

Comment: OK got it. I'd suggest to use variable name like `av_X1_to_X3` for this.

Comment: Yeah sorry if this was misleading